# JQuery function error in code ReplaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting create error in console while i use to replaceWith function of jquery.

```js
 $("#fetchvalue").replaceWith('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subcategorytwo" value="+opt_subcat_two+" id="fetchvalue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+opt+'</input>');
```

I have added screen of error, i have tired a lot solve it but, i FAILED.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $( "#fetchvalue" ).replaceWith('<a type="text" class="form-control" name="subcategorytwo" value="" id="fetchvalue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+opt+'</a>');
```

Updated answer as per comment

```
var opt =1;
var opt_subcat_two =2;
$( "#fetchvalue" ).replaceWith('<a type="text" class="form-control" name="subcategorytwo" value='+opt_subcat_two+' id="fetchvalue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+opt+'</a>');
```

Comment: if i use single quotes, then unable to give this attribute into this code: `value="+opt_subcat_two+"`

Comment: this is great answer but, its giving me as value = 2 and display also = 2... why it is not displaying/view as = 1

Comment: should i use <input> instead of <a >?

Answer (score 2):

Since your string contains double quotes, use single quotes as a string delimiter, or escape the double quotes within the string.  Here's an example using single quotes a string delimiter:

```
$("#fetchvalue").replaceWith('<a type="text" class="form-control" name="subcategorytwo" value="" id="fetchvalue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+opt+'</a>');
```

I'm guessing `opt` is a variable and as such does not need to be inside quotes at all.

Update, with a value attribute:

```
$("#fetchvalue").replaceWith('<a type="text" class="form-control" name="subcategorytwo" value="' + opt_subcat_two + '" id="fetchvalue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+opt+'</a>');
```

Comment: if i use single quotes, then unable to give this attribute into this code: `value="+opt_subcat_two+"`

Comment: You are missing the single quotes.  It should be value=" ' + opt_subcat_two + ' " ...

Comment: you are right but, its give me value `opt` and display value also `opt` why it is not displaying `opt_subcat_two`

Comment: should i use <input> instead of <a >?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do .... you are replacing an input element with an anchor element, those are completely different elements with different attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all the double quotes you use inside the argument to replaceWith:

`$( "#fetchvalue" ).replaceWith("<a type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"subcategorytwo\" value=\"\" id=\"fetchvalue\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\">"+"opt"+"</a>");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the right '. Instead of " use '

```js
var opt=7;
var opt_subcat_two=11;
$( "#fetchvalue" ).replaceWith("<a type='text' href='#' class='form-control' name='subcategorytwo' value="+opt_subcat_two+" id='fetchvalue' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'> "+opt+"</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fetchvalue"></div>
```

Comment: if i use single quotes, then unable to give this attribute into this code: `value="+opt_subcat_two+"`

Comment: The whole idea is to use different quotes inside the string then what are used to enclose the whole string. Check the edits.